# Read a line from file in C and extract the number of input

Tags: c, scanf, fgets, fread

I have a file **input.dat**. In this file, there are 3 lines:

```
1 2 3
5 7 10 12
8 9 14 13 15 17
```

I am going to read one of the three lines using C, and return the number of the elements.
For example, I want to read the 2nd line `5 7 10 12` into memory, and also return the number of values in the 2nd line, which is `4`. My code is below...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 2000

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("in.dat", "r");
    char line[STRING_SIZE];
    int lcount = 0, nline = 1, sum = 0, number;

    if (fp != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, STRING_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
            if (lcount == nline) {
                while (sscanf(line, "%d ", &number)) {
                    sum++;
                }
                break;
            } else {
                lcount++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

When I run this code, it never stops like a dead loop. What is the problem here?

Comment: `scanf` advances the stream.  `sscanf` does not advance the string.  You're just reading from the same place each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the loop `while (sscanf(line, "%d ", &number))` keeps parsing the first number in the line.

You should use `strtol` instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 2000

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("in.dat", "r");
    char line[STRING_SIZE];
    int lcount = 0, nline = 1;

    if (fp != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, STRING_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
            if (lcount == nline) {
                char *p = line, *q;
                int count = 0;
                for (;;) {
                    long val = strtol(p, &q, 0);    // parse an integer
                    if (q == p) {
                        // end of string or not a number
                        break;
                    }
                    // value was read into val. You can use it for whatever purpose
                    count++;
                    p = q;
                }
                printf("%d\n", count);
                break;
            } else {
                lcount++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @David: `strtol` returns the value read. You can set `errno` to `0` prior to calling `strtol` and check if it was changed by `strtol` to indicate that the value converted was outside the range of type `long`, in which case the returned value it either `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` depending on the sign of the converted value.

Answer (score 1):

A bit cleaner version of **chqrlie**'s answer. Started with a string as that is what the question is really about after `fgets()`.

`sscanf()` won't step through the string, it always reads from the beginning.

`strtol()` looks for a `long int` in the beginning of the string, ignoring initial white-space. Gives back the address of where it stops scanning.

The manual of `strtol()` says that errno should be checked for any conversion error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 2000

int main(void)
{
    char line[STRING_SIZE] = "5 7 10 12";

    char* start = line;
    char* end;

    int count = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        /**
         * strtol() look for long int in beginning of the string
         * Ignores beginning whitespace
         * 
         * start: where to strtol() start looking for long int
         * end: where strtol() stops scanning for long int
         */
        errno = 0; // As strol() manual says

        strtol(start, &end, 0);

        if (errno != 0)
        {
            printf("Error in strtol() conversion.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        if (start == end) break; // Quit loop

        start = end;
        count++;
    }
    

    printf("count: %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Added error checking as the man page says.

Comment: Good job, now the conversion is fully validated.

Comment: Checking `errno` does not seem necessary: it will be set only for numbers outside the range of type `long`. `sscanf(line, "%d", &number)` would have undefined behavior for these numbers anyway, and even smaller ones if `INT_MAX < LONG_MAX`. The OP wants the number of values and did not specify any range restriction.

Answer (score 1):

You were thinking along the right path with your use of `sscanf()`, the only piece of the puzzle you were missing is how to apply an offset to `line` so that you read the next value in the line with your next call to `sscanf()`. You do that by keeping track of the number of characters consumed on each call to `sscanf()` using the `"%n"` conversion (it does not add to your conversion count returned by `sscanf()`) For example reading lines from the open file-stream `fp`, you could do:

```
#define MAXC  1024      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    char line[MAXC] = "";   /* buffer to hold each line */
    ...
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {    /* reach each line in file */
        int offset = 0,                 /* offset in line for next sscanf() read */
            nchr = 0,                   /* number of char consumed by last read */
            val,                        /* integer value read with sscanf() */
            nval = 0;                   /* number of values read in line */
        /* conververt each integer at line + offset, saving no. of chars consumed */
        while (sscanf (line + offset, "%d%n", &val, &nchr) == 1) {
            printf (" %d", val);        /* output value read */
            offset += nchr;             /* update offset with no. chars consumend */
            nval++;                     /* increment value count */
        }
        printf ("  -  %d values\n", nval);  /* output no. values in line */
    }
```

(**Note:** `strtol()` provides better error reporting than `sscanf()` on a failed conversion)

If you put it together with an example that reads from the filename provided as the first argument to the program (or reads from `stdin` by default if no argument is given), you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC  1024      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[MAXC] = "";   /* buffer to hold each line */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {    /* reach each line in file */
        int offset = 0,                 /* offset in line for next sscanf() read */
            nchr = 0,                   /* number of char consumed by last read */
            val,                        /* integer value read with sscanf() */
            nval = 0;                   /* number of values read in line */
        /* conververt each integer at line + offset, saving no. of chars consumed */
        while (sscanf (line + offset, "%d%n", &val, &nchr) == 1) {
            printf (" %d", val);        /* output value read */
            offset += nchr;             /* update offset with no. chars consumend */
            nval++;                     /* increment value count */
        }
        printf ("  -  %d values\n", nval);  /* output no. values in line */
    }

    if (fp != stdin)                    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With the data you show in the filename `dat/nvals.txt` you would get:

```
$ ./bin/fgetsnvals dat/nvals.txt
 1 2 3  -  3 values
 5 7 10 12  -  4 values
 8 9 14 13 15 17  -  6 values
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: *`strtol()` provides better error reporting than `sscanf()` on a failed conversion*: indeed it does! `strtol()` will set `errno` to `ERANGE` for values outside the range of type `long` whereas `sscanf()` will have undefined behavior if the converted value cannot be represented as an `int`, but it would take a perverse implementation to not consume all the digits which is sufficient to count the values.

Comment: @chqrlie no question about it. But since you both had `strtol()` covered, and the OP had started with a `sscanf()` approach, I figured I would fill that blank in `:)`